# Javascript Web Worker in a Loop

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm map()ing 2 things, and in each map iteration I'm using a web worker to get a value that I want to assign to the thing that was the thing during the iteration when the web worker call was made. My issue is that the map finishes iterating before the web worker can respond, so all values it returns are assigned to the last "thing" that was iterated. What are some good patterns for this situation? Thanks, Ted

Comment: without your code, I can only assume you don't know how to work with asynchronous code

Comment: I think I'll pass a specific ID for each call, and make a look-up object that relates the returned value - call ID - thing w/ property to update.

Answer (score 0):

In my map loop before each web worker call, I created a unique ID for the call. I created an object keyed by this ID to track the loop indexes that the call related to. I fed the ID into and out of the web worker and used it to assign the values returned from the worker.